# Optimizing Smart Client Performance

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wcf, web-services

I have a smart client (WPF) that makes calls to the server va services (WCF). The screen I am working on holds a list of objects that it loads when the constructor is called.  I am able to add, edit and delete records in the list.

Typically what I am doing is after every add or delete I am reloading the entire model from the service again, there are a number off reasons for this including the fact that the data may have changed on the server between calls.

This approach has proved to be a big hit on perfomance because I am loading everything sending the list up and down the wire on Add and Edit.

What other options are open to me, should I only be send the required information to the server and how would I go about not reloading all the data again ever time an add or delete is performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal way of doing what you're describing (I'm going to assume that you know that client/server I/O is the bottleneck already) is to send only changes in both directions once the client is populated.

This can be straightforward if you've adopted a journaling model for updates to the data.  In order for any process to make a change to the shared data, it has to create a time-stamped transaction that gets added to a journal.  The update to the data is made by a method that applies the transaction to the data.

Once your data model supports transaction journals, you have a straightforward way of keeping the client and server in sync with a minimum of network traffic:  to update the client, the server sends all of the journal entries that have been created since the last time the client was updated.

This can be a considerable amount of work to retrofit into an existing design.  Before you go down this road, you want to be sure that the problem you're trying to fix is in fact the problem that you have.

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure this functionality is well-encapsulated so you can play with it without having to touch other components.
2. Have your source under version control and check in often.
3. I highly recommend having a suite of automated unit tests to verify that everything works as expected before refactoring and continues to work as you perform each change.
4. If the performance hit is on the server->client transfer of data, moreso than the querying, processing and disk IO on the server, you could consider devising a hash of a given collection or graph of objects, and passing the hash to a service method on the server, which would query and calculate the hash from the db, compare the hashes, and return `true` or `false`. Only if `false` would you then reload data. This works if changes are unlikely or infrequent, because it requires two calls to get the data, when it has changed. If changes in the db are a concern, you might not want to only get the changes when the user modifies or adds something -- this might be a completely separate action based on a timer, for example. Your concurrency strategy really depends on your data, number of users, likelihood of more than one user being interested in changing the same data at the same time, etc.

Comment: You know this is about more than a question's title, right? The question is about optimization, and that's just due diligence before touching optimization. I could understand the downvote if my answer were *only* 1,2 & 3, but not for being comprehensive about engineering practices. Still, I'll answer your question. In order to gauge and compare the performance effect of a given change, one needs to keep versions from each implementation. In order to make this practical, the system being worked on should be well encapsulated. To make it efficient, you have to know if it works, thus tests.